# Update SharePoint Library HyperLink or Picture Column Automatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, microsoft-flow

Scenario:
I have Power Apps collecting information including a camera photo, this is being sent to a document library (Using a content type) as attachment along with other metadata. I have used this tutorial by Paul O'Flaherty to do this using Flow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6xMLprDTjU

Once in the document library I can manually set the hyperlink/photo field to the new file uploaded so i then get a nice thumbnail in the document library view.
This picture also naturally becomes a profile picture within the power app.

How do i get this hyperlink column to automatically point to the items file?
Thanks

Comment: Why not use an Image Library? It does this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use column formatting if your list view is modern....

Using column formatting You can customize rendering of any field using json object and also refer to another column for conditional rendering or based on your need. Please check below link...

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Comment: The hyperlink column is not an option to select for formatting, only entire row and the remaining columns are displayed. The guidance on the hyperlink you attached does state you can format the hyperlink column but does not show how. Will this just be formatting or will it actually set the VALUE of the column so other lists and PowerApps can retrieve the value?

Comment: a hyperlink can be formatted.....click on down arrow on hyperlink field and click on column formatting.... this will be just formatting and it does not actually set value of the column so lists and powerapps will still retrieve the actual VALUE...

Comment: At the moment the hyperlink column is blank - I want it to have thevalue of the file attached in the library!, i need the value of the hyperlink column to point to the file in the same library. When i select the down arrow on the column and select format column it says for entire column, the drop down does not have the hyperlink column to select, only the title and name and other columns....perhaps you can supply the JSON that can set one field to another?